# Do IntelliJ plugins take a significant amount of memory?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it worth it to disable plugins that I'm not using, or is the perf cost negligable on a modern installation (IntelliJ 10.5, modern machine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth disabling plug-ins that you don't use, but not to save memory. Disabling them will give you cleaner UI without unnecessary menu options and settings.

Performance wise, you will not gain much on a modern hardware as IDEA uses lazy loading and initialization, it will not load plug-ins that are not used in the current project.